# Why isn't my dplyr function working in R markdown?

Tags: r, markdown

[This](https://gyazo.com/de4da65923d4644bc50b198e4484a5e3) chunk is not working. Packets are already loaded. My R Studio and R latest version right now. I tried this and still not working:

```
dplyr::select()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misunderstood how `dplyr::select()` works. First of all, I recommend you reading our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), then you should always try ask questions with a sample dataset, one that is similar to the one that you're working with so we can reproduce your error and then give you a possible solution. If you have questions on how to do that, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Ok, second I think you should understand how `dplyr::select()` works. It's not hard to understand, `select` returns you the selected columns of a given data frame. You can do this with the following expression

```
select(data_frame, column)
```

So, in this code snippet that you gave to us:

```
select(mpg, class)
```

You are trying to remove the `class` column of  the `mpg` dataset, which we (the stackoverflow people) don't know even if it exists! But I do believe you'are trying to collect the `mpg` column of the mtcars dataset, that's already built in R, if I'm right you can do that running the following code:

```
select(mtcars, mpg)
```